# Is it possible to use a type other than uint64_t for a table primary key?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, table

I want to use a uint128_t as a primary key in a multi_index table. Is this possible? If so, how should the ABI file be written to accomodate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official documentation you can find [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/using-multi-index-tables#section-introduction):

> They are multi index tables because they support using multiple indexes on the data, the primary index type must be uint64_t and must be unique, but the other, secondary, indexes can have duplicates. You can have up to 16 additional indexes and the field types can be uint64_t, uint128_t, uint256_t, double or long double

So it seems that only `uint64_t` are allowed for primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Only `uint64_t` can be used as a primary key.

However, you can try to do what you want in a slightly different way: using `uint128_t` it as a secondary index.

```
struct [[eosio::table]] youtable
{
    name key;
    uint128_t your_value;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value; }
    uint128_t get_your_value() const { return your_value; }
};
```